# How to bind a list of POCO objects to Windows Forms DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms

I've not really done any windows forms before, and I am attempting to create a simple app for me to view my message logging service.

I thought the simplest way to do this would be with a DataGridView control. How do you bind a simple list of objects to it and have the column headings etc auto generated?

I have done this so far and it creates the columns with headings but no rows/data.

```
List<Log> logs = loggingRepo.LoadAll();

logGrid.DataSource = logs;
```

I would have expected there to be a `logGrid.DataBind()` method like list views in ASP.NET but there doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: Have you checked if the list contains any item ??

Comment: haha god you hit the nail on the head!! how stupid do I feel :)

Answer (score 4):

There's no databind, the setting of DataSource takes place immediately.

Binding to POCOs isn't great though, you end up with a less than optimal experience for the user.  I'd wrap the logs collection in a BindingList, that should enable some basic sorting and filtering.

Comment: cheers - poco's are fine for this use though I am the only user!

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure in case it did matter.